# Cannot access Windows Shares on Win-7 from Ubuntu 10.04 after Copied files from another Win-7

Tags: 10.04, windows-7, samba, smb

Hi I know Samba problems is all over the places. But I am through with searching none of the solution worked for me (Disable firewall, Install that lib, Config smb.conf and stuffs)

Actually the windows share is accessible from Ubuntu without any problem, but not until there's file transfer from another Win-7 machine to/from the shared folder. Then none of my ubuntu machine can access the share again until WIN7 is rebooted.

$smbtree will show ..

```
\\WIN7
failed negprot: ERRnomen
```

$smbclient -L WIN7

```
protocol negotiation failed: ERRnomem
```

and as always, nautilus will show

```
Could not display "smb://WIN7/folder"
Error: Failed to mount Windows share
Please select another viewer and try again.
```

Any clue?  Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tweak Windows 7 side: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-7-samba-errnomem.html

Set

```
Computer\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size
```

to `3`

```
Computer\HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\LargeSystemCache
```

to `1`

> No need to reboot or anything, the change will take place on the fly.